# Why under Texlive2014 / win8.1 terminal xelatex does not work outside the bin/win32 directory?

Tags: xetex, windows

When I open the terminal and type `xelatex`, the program ended without any prompt.
[image]

It only works when I changed the directory to `texlive/2014/bin/win32`
[image]

This is rather odd since if the program path is not specified in the system (which is not the case), it should simply prompt a message saying the command is not found. In my case, no information is shown at all.

My system path is shown below:
[image]

Does anyone know what is happening here?

Comment: Presumably, TeXLive have not properly been added to the system PATH. Just for the fun of it, have you tried closing all commands prompts and starting a new one and tried running `xelatex` outside the `win32` dir once more? It may also be an idea to verify that TeXLive is listed in the system `PATH`. I have no idea how to verify on the prompt on Windows.

Comment: Addition: You can see the current PATH using `set PATH` on the command prompt. That should list the `PATH` variable.

Comment: @daleif I have already done it when I posted this question. Doesn't help.

Comment: What doesn't help? Exactly what is listed in the PATH variable?

Comment: @daleif I think I'd go with `echo %PATH%` for preference

Comment: @JosephWright, I'm clearly not a windows user.

Comment: @daleif Your first comment doesn't help: I am sure texlive\2014\bin\win32 is in the path. I feel that you are making fun of me and I don't appreciate that. I will suggest you to stop commenting here, leaving place for useful comments.

Comment: @TroyWoo Not at all, but since you are the only person with access to this particular computer we need to you provide more information and be explicitly clear as to what you are referring to when answering. Do you mind running Josephs suggestion in a terminal and post a picture of it like above. That way we can verify that nothing fishy is wrong with the data in that variable.

Comment: It looks ok, but (1) Why is TL listed twice, and (2) is the space in the first occurence `\win32 ;` problematic? (I'm not a windows user). There is definitely and explicit space there in front of the `;` it is not present in all of the the other paths in the list.

Comment: BTW: just for comparison, can you start `pstoedit` (it is listed last in the path)

Comment: @daleif TL shown twice because I added them to both user path and system path. Nothing wrong the space, its just format display problem when appending user path after system path. pstoedit starts fine.

Comment: I don't think that the path variable is the problem. If xelatex wouldn't be recognized as a command then window should complain. That xelatex silently returns to the prompt is curious. Did you try to call xelatex from other folders than `users\admin` too? Is there perhaps some other application with the name xelatex in your path? Did you try xelatex --help?

Comment: I'm guessing that `pdflatex` does not work out of the `win32` folder either? I;m waiting for my Win8.1 VM to update, before I test some of this.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thats just what I thought. I searched possible duplicates of xelatex before I posted this post, and found nothing.

Comment: Did you search for all sorts of executables? Did you check the current folder? Does your windows show hidden files? Put the texlive path to the front of your path variable: `set path=C:\...;%path%`. Move to another empty folder. If it works then then it is quite probably that another xelatex is in the path.

Comment: Just as a test I did the following: (1) installed a minimal TL14. (2) Created `pdflatex.bat` that just runs `echo test`. (3) Moved `pdflatex.bat` into `c:\windows\system32`. Now, if I run `pdflatex` anywhere else than `texlive/2014/bin/win32` it says `test`. But inside `win32` it gives me the normal `pdflatex` prompt. So @UlrikeFischer seems to have a point. You should search your computer a but more through to see if there are multiple `xelatex.*` on the computer. Also an idea to test by adding the TL path in front as Ulrike suggested.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Moving the TL path to the beginning works...I am sure there is no other file named xelatex.exe or any executable.

Comment: It doesn't need to be another xelatex, it could be another xetex, or some library used by xetex.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a subtle issue, which I have also run into. Firstly, `xelatex.exe` is a very simple wrapper around `xetex.exe`, whose source we can find in `xtx\texk\xelatex\xelatex.c` of [`w32tex-src.tar.xz`](http://w32tex.org/). Basically it simply executes

```
return spawnvp(_P_WAIT, "xetex.exe", argv);
```

Now, this [`spawnvp`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/275khfab.aspx) function has an unexpected behavior. First, it tries to execute `.\xelatex.exe`. If this fails, it falls back to parsing `PATH`. It does this by trying to run `spawnve` on every element of `PATH`, and to my surprise it aborts as soon as one of the directories in `PATH` is malformed in some way! (In other words, as soon as `errno` is not `ENOENT` after `spawnve`; when a directory is malformed, `errno` is `EINVAL` instead.)

This obviously explains why running `xelatex.exe` in its native directory works, and also why it works when its directory is the first entry in `PATH`. But as soon as an entry in `PATH` is malformed (e.g., when two paths are concatenated without a separating `;` character), every other directory afterwards is ignored, and this is why `xelatex.exe` failed in my case.